# Retrieve facebook contact's birthday and add to google calendar for WP7

Tags: c#, php, javascript, facebook

how to do in easy way in `php` or something equal (`c#`/`js`) ?

I need to get all of my facebook contacts (but only contacts with birthday) to create a text file compatible with google calendar?
In my Windows Phone 7 i would to show birthday from google calendar.

How to do it?
What library i need?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in HTML and Javascript only, you don't have to use C#.

See http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/481 - it's a sample where you pull the movies your friends like and then the movies are ranked by number of likes. Though it's not directly related to what you want, it shows how to authenticate and work with the facebook API using Javascript.

For your task specifically, look into the friendslist API -http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to do this on a phone you don't need to use PHP.

To do the Facebook integration, you should look at the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/).

For Google Calendar integration, look at their [Data API Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html).

Comment: No, i do not do it on phone... but on windows and import in google calendar my custom txt file that is visible from wp7. thanks

Comment: @Paska If the fact the calendar is being subscribed to by a phone is irrelevant to interacting with either Facebook or adding the data to a Google calendar why tag your question "Windows-Phone-7"? You may also want to update the question to make it clearer what you're trying to do.